# How can I find theta of following Recurrence

Tags: sorting

How can we find theta of this equation.
T(n)=2T(n/2)+n^2/logn
For above question cannot use master theorem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be [image]

Consider the recursion tree generated by this recurrence relation. The depth would be [image] because it would take [image] calls to get n to be 1, through dividing n by 2 over and over. The "width", or the total run time at every level of the tree is [image: s] because every time you divide the tree into 2, you also double the value (2T(n/2)). So multiplying the height by the width gives you [image] which is [image]